# How to convert a timestamp in correct object of date?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

How to convert a timestamp in correct object of date?

---

4 opinion for choose:

1. new Date(timestamp)
2. new Date(timestamp * 1000)
3. parseDate(timestamp)
4. Date.parse(timestamp)

Comment: or use moment.js var day = moment.unix(timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Accepted Solution was if talk about **UNIX** timestamps to JavaScript Object

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```